# Swift: checking 2 object from same class have different values?

Tags: swift

I'm using swift in my project. I have 2 object from same class(for example object A and object B from Class MyClass):

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    var someString: String = ""
    var someInt: Int = 0
}
...
let A = MyClass()
A.someString = "A object"
A.someInt = 1

let B = MyClass()
B.someString = "B object"
B.someInt = 2
```

how I can check if same properties have same value, and if not return value and key of the property?

I think we can do this with using Mirror with 2 for loop inside each other, am I write?

Comment: Do you need to do this for any class or just a specific one?

Comment: for specific class

Comment: So you could simply do something like `if a.someString != b.someString { return ("someString", a.someString) } ` in a function?

Comment: I used some simple class (only 2 properties), imagine a class with 20 properties. then what should I do?

Comment: Ok, just trying to understand what you want to accomplish

Comment: do you think we can use KVO?

Comment: Yes but then you would need to write specific code for each property which I got the impression you didn't want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this pretty much:

```
import Foundation

class MyClass {
    var someString: String = ""
    var someInt: Int = 0
}

let a = MyClass()
a.someString = "A object"
a.someInt = 1

let b = MyClass()
b.someString = "B object"
b.someInt = 2

func compare<T: MyClass>(_ instance: T, with instance2: T) -> [String: AnyHashable] {
    let sourceMirror = Mirror(reflecting: instance)
    let targetMirror = Mirror(reflecting: instance2)
    
    var output = [String: AnyHashable]()
    
    for sourceChild in sourceMirror.children {
        guard let label = sourceChild.label else { continue }
        
        guard let targetChild = (targetMirror.children.first { $0.label! == label }) else {
            fatalError("Failed to find target child, since types are same this fatal error should not be fired")
        }
        
        guard
            let firstValue = sourceChild.value as? AnyHashable,
            let secondValue = targetChild.value as? AnyHashable
        else {
            continue
        }
        
        guard firstValue != secondValue else { continue }
        
        output[label] = secondValue
    }
    
    return output
}

for result in compare(a, with: b) {
    print("label: \(result.key), value: \(result.value)")
}
```

The downside of this method is all of your fields must be conforming to Hashable protocol if you want to see the difference between these.

The output is:

```
label: someInt, value: 2
label: someString, value: B object
```